# Toolbar does not show up in Xamarin.Android

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm trying to replace an `ActionBar` with a toolbar, but the toolbar doesn't show up. I don't understand why my page is still blank without the toolbar, what am I missing?

My style:

```
  <style name="MyThemeActionBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>  
  </style>
```

My toolbar.axml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:id="@+id/toolbar"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
  android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
  android:layout_width="match_parent">

  <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/toolbartitile"
    android:text="Kodej"/>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

My activity:

```
[Activity(Label = "MainLoginActivity" , Theme = "@style/MyThemeActionBar")]
public class MainLoginActivity : AppCompatActivity
{
    private ISharedPreferences sp;
    private Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar toolbar;

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.MainLogin);

        toolbar = FindViewById<Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar>(Resource.Id.toolbar);
        SetSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        sp = GetSharedPreferences(null, FileCreationMode.Private);

        TextView tv = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.emailMain);
        tv.Text = sp.GetString("email", null);

        tv.Click += (object sender, EventArgs e) =>
        {
            Android.Support.V7.App.AlertDialog.Builder ad = new Android.Support.V7.App.AlertDialog.Builder(this);

            ad.SetTitle("Logout");
            ad.SetMessage("Are you sure you want to logout");

            ad.SetPositiveButton("Yes", (senderAlert, args) => 
            {
                ISharedPreferencesEditor editor = sp.Edit();
                editor.Remove("email");
                editor.Apply();

                StartActivity(typeof(MainActivity));

                Finish();
            });

            ad.SetNegativeButton("Cancel", (senderAlert, args) => {});

            Dialog dialog = ad.Create();
            dialog.Show();
        };

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem could be with the code:

```
toolbar = FindViewById<Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar>(Resource.Id.toolbar);
```

Since you didn't post your code of your `MainLogin` layout, when you code this in your `MainLoginActivity`, the context is `MainLoginActivity`, and you should make sure there is a `Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar` which ID is `toolbar` existing in the `MainLogin` layout, otherwise, this will return a `null`, and it won't throw an exception when you `SetSupportActionBar(toolbar);`.

To solve this issue, you can:

1. Move your layout for your `Toolbar` into `MainLogin` layout.
2. Or keep your `Toolbar` in your toolbar layout but use it in your `MainLogin` layout for example like this:

MainLogin layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
  <include android:id="@+id/toolbar"
           layout="@layout/mytoolbar" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: unfortunatly i had forgot this post but yeah you are right the error was that i had forgot to put it in the mainlogin but thank you (You just learn me that i can use <include> so thank you)

Comment: @jgauthier, then if this answer helps, could you please [mark this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)?